# Show all prioritized items in sublistings

Tags: org-mode

I have trees of tasks in org-mode. They are organized into several headings, and subheadings. I have prioritized items at every level.

Is there a way to show all the prioritized item from all subheading levels by priority. For example all the #A items, or all the #b items?

I have a bunch of things with priorities and some without. I want to have a way to just see the prioritized items.

Comment: I was just asking something very similar: [link to item in org document](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69125/link-to-item-in-org-document)

Comment: List them where? In the agenda? If so, try a custom agenda command (`C-h i g (org)Custom Agenda Views`). Also [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql)

Comment: It looks that lists (the ones starting with `-` or similar) are just text. To get the functionality we want we need headlines. Check this little 42 pages org-mode guide. Particularly ch5 at page 10 https://orgmode.org/orgguide.pdf

Comment: The word "list" has different meanings and I'm not sure you are using it in the same way the OP does: in particular, you are referring to "itemized lists" as narrowly specified in Org mode, whereas the OP is talking much more generically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an unsorted sparse tree of all lines (unfortunately not just headlines) containing a priority cookie within an individual Org file:

```
C-c / (or M-x org-sparse-tree)
r (to enter a pattern)
\[#[ABC]]\] RET
```

The pattern means: left square bracket, then `#`, then either `A` or `B` or `C` (the default set of priorities), then right square bracket.

Use the pattern `\[#B\]` for only priority B, etc.

See `(info "(org) Sparse Trees")`.

You might want to submit a bug report/request for enhancement asking to add an option for creating priority sparse trees to the existing set of options (TODO state, tags, properties etc). It seems like a good idea to me.

```
M-x org-submit-bug-report
```